# Return names which exist in second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently trying to populate a dropdown list with labels that need to exist in a second dataframe, currently, the below is returning a True and False option:

```
[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in sorted(dff.Opp.isin(df2['Name']).unique().astype(str))],
```

any advice on what needs to be changed?

EDIT: DataFrame examples:

```
df1:
0  Opp
1  Test2
2  Test4
3  Test6
4  Test7

df2:
0  Name
1  Test1
2  Test2
3  Test3
4  Test4
5  Test5
```

Expected outcome:
dropdown would be populated with Test2 and Test4 as they are in both dataframes

Comment: can you provide both the data frames and desired output?

Comment: @DevinSmith please provide data

Comment: Looks like you might want: `[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in set(dff.Opp).intersection(df['Name'])]`...

Comment: Added sample dataframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're currently working with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). I tried to reproduce your issue with the code below. From the [official document](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html?highlight=series%20isin#pandas-series-isin),

> `pandas.Series.isin` returns Series of booleans indicating if each element is in values.

you need to filter values in the Series with `loc` function before calling `.unique()`

```py
dff = pd.DataFrame(data={"Opp": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={"Name": ["a", "e"]})

dff.loc[dff['Opp'].isin(df2['Name']), 'Opp'].unique()

# Output:
# array(['a', 'e'], dtype=object)
```

#### Solution

```py
[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in sorted(dff.loc[dff['Opp'].isin(df2['Name']), 'Opp'].unique())]

# Output:
# [{'label': 'a', 'value': 'a'}, {'label': 'e', 'value': 'e'}]
```